# Logic evaluation problem in SUMPRODUCT Formula

Tags: excel

I am using a formula based on `SUMPRODUCT`, `SUBTOTAL`, and `OFFSET`. To enable count of visible rows only with criteria. I a trying it on a simple sample data which as follows. Data starts from `B4` in the Range `B4:B12` Header B3:

```
B Column
HD
2
2
4
6
2
1
8
9
2
```

Formula is :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B4:B12=B4)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0))))
```

It gives correct result of 4 counts for a value of 2.
I went for evaluation of the formula to fully understand its logic. I could comprehend major part of its logic but certain steps are not quite clear to me. I am reproducing evaluation steps below with my comments.

Step -1

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({2;2;4;6;2;1;8;9;2}=2)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0))))
```

OK

Step -2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0))))
```

OK

STEP-3

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0))))
```

OK

STEP-4

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($B$4,{4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}-MIN({4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}),0))))
```

OK

STEP-5

```
=SUMPRODUCT(({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE})*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($B$4,{4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}-4),0))))
```

OK

STEP-6

```
=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET($B$4,{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8},0))))
```

Why `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}` ??

STEP-7

```
=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}*(SUBTOTAL(103,{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;})))
```

Why `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;}` ??
STEP-8

```
=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}*({1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}))
```

How `1`  instead of `#VALUE!`
STEP-9

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;1})
```

OK

Step -10

```
 4
```

OK

I am not having full clarity on the following points

STEP-6 : Why `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}`

STEP-7: Why `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;}`

STEP-8: How `1`  instead of `#VALUE!`

Hope Someone helps in clarifying the logic behind these mentioned spots. Please forgive me  for asking clarity on such a trivial matter.

Comment: Step 6 is the result of `ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)` so you are taking 4 away from the rows to get a 0 based index

Comment: In terms of STEP 7 - I would assume `B$4$:B$12` all result in #VALUE errors? - If not could you confirm the values inside of them or like values if it's sensitive data

Comment: I have reproduced steps by taking screenshots of various steps during Formula Evaluation taking help of Evaluate Formula in the Formula tab of the Ribbon. There we do not get any values other then mentioned by me. I have already mentioned data values used by me in first paragraph of the question itself. Thanks for your interest and time in the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STEP-6 : Why `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}`

Because the `{4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12}-4` evaluates to `{4-4;5-4;6-4;7-4;8-4;9-4;10-4;11-4;12-4}` which is `{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8}`

STEP-7: Why `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}`

The formula evaluator fails getting the values out of the 9 cell references got via `OFFSET($B$4,{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8},0)` = `{$B$4;$B$5;$B$6;$B$7;$B$8;$B$9;$B$10;$B$11;$B$12}` in array context. But that does not matter because:

STEP-8: How `1` instead of `#VALUE!`

the `SUBTOTAL(103,...` is a `COUNTA` subtotal which, for each single cell reference of the 9 cell references got in step 7, counts 1 if it is not hidden, else 0. So it does not matter whether the cell values was evaluated or not.

Btw.: The same can be achieved using

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B4:B12=B4)*(SUBTOTAL(103,INDIRECT("B"&ROW(B4:B12)))))
```

Annotation:
Such formulas are result of trial and error. I doubt any `Excel` programmer was able predicting all usages of the functions they implemented. There are usages of `Excel` functions in the wild which are as much thought outside the box that they  originally could not have thought so.

---

Bonus:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0))
```

results in 0 using your values in `B4:B12`.

Here the formula evaluator also fails getting the values out of the 9 cell references got via `OFFSET($B$4,{0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8},0)` = `{$B$4;$B$5;$B$6;$B$7;$B$8;$B$9;$B$10;$B$11;$B$12}` in array context. And the result is `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}`. But now it matters because we need the values.

In that case we can use `N` function to force getting the values

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(B4,ROW(B4:B12)-MIN(ROW(B4:B12)),0)))
```

This results in 36, the sum of your values in `B4:B12`.

Comment: After applying filter for values greater then 4 I am getting correct result as 0.. Step 7 array  is still showing `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;}`  but Step 8 correctly shows `({0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;0})` resulting in `0`. So it evaluates correctly but shows all positions as `#VALUE!;` You are really a genious. Thanks for providing clarity. Any view point on this strange `#VALUE!;` reflection in step 7.

Comment: @skkakkar: "You are really a genious.": Clearly not. As of my annotation, the `Excel` programmers are the giants on whose shoulders we stand.